# Evolutive string substitution

Tags: javascript, jquery, substitution

I builded a JQuery component to make a dropdown-accordion element. Each time i click on a item in a accordion, it will save the selection, close this accordion andopen the next one if exists.

To add data, it work as it :

```
$(window).ready(function () {
    $(selector).data('dropdownaccordion').enqueueAccordion({ // Ajax parameter
            name: "Commune",
            data: {
                url: "/trends/list",
                method: 'GET',
                datatype: "json",
                timeout: 5000
            }
        },
        {
            name: "Batiment",
            data: {
                url: "/trends/list/"+this.path[0], // this.path[0] refer to the first selection, as this.path[1] will refer to the second etc
                method: 'GET',
                datatype: "json",
                timeout: 5000
            }
        },
        { //Note that we can pass array instead of Ajax parameter
            name: "Dummy",
            data: ["One", "Two", "Three"]
        })
});
```

I designed the component to work good with Rest API.

The problem is exposed for the second element i added. As you can see, i'm trying to pass this.path[0], refering to **the first item selected**. But the property path doesn't exist in the $(windows).ready scope, but in the $(selector).data('dropdownaccordion') scope.

I can replace it by `$(selector).data('dropdownaccordion').path[0]`, but i want something more global, like ExpressJS do in URL (http://www.dummy.com/path/:item1/:item2 and replacing :itemx by the user selection)

Do you know a better solution, and if not, do you know a way to make it good ?

### EDIT

My Component is designed as follow :

```
+function ($) {
    'use strict';
    /**
     * Dropdown_Accordion CLASS DEFINITION
     */
    function DropdownAccordion(component, ...accordions) {
        this.accordions = [];

        for(var i=0;i<accordions.length;i++){
            this.accordions.push(accordions[i])
        }

        ...
        this.component = $(component);

        ...
        // Render the accordions as DOM
        this.render.call(this);

        //Events
        this.component
            .on("click", ".accordion-item-body", $.proxy(function(event){
                this.path.push($(event.target).text())
                this.component.trigger('click.selection.dropdownaccordion', [$(event.target)])
                this.openNext(event);
            }, this))
            .on('show.bs.dropdown', $.proxy(this.showMenu, this))
            .on('shown.bs.dropdown', $.proxy(this.openNext, this))
            .on('hide.bs.dropdown', $.proxy(function (event) {
                this.component.find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp();
                this.component.find(".accordion-item .panel-collapse.collapse").each(function(){
                    $(this).collapse('hide');
                });
                this.opened = null;
                (this.path.length !== this.accordions.length) ? this.component.trigger("abort.selection.dropdownaccordion", [this.path]):null
                this.path = []
            }, this));
    }

    DropdownAccordion.prototype = {
        constructor: DropdownAccordion,
        // Collapse accordion every time dropdown is shown
        showMenu: function () {
            // show the accordion
        },

        openNext: function (clickEvent) {
           // Open the next accordion
        },

        render: function () {
            // Will render the dropdown-accordion
            // The following is how the AJAX request is performed
            ...
            // When the accordion is opened, make the ajax request
            DOMaccordion.on("open.accordion.dropdownaccordion", function () {
                    // The DOM element contains in data the options for the ajax request, or nothing if the accordion is an array    
                    **$.ajax($(this).data('content.accordion.dropdownaccordion'))** 

            });
            ...
            }
        },
        enqueueAccordion: function (...accordions) {
            for(var i=0; i<accordions.length;i++)
                this.accordions.push(accordions[i]);
            this.render()
        },

        dequeueAccordion: function (name) {
            this.accordions = this.accordions.filter(function (obj) {
                return obj.name !== name;
            })
            this.render()
        }
    }
```

Look at the ** ** in the code, this is where the Ajax options is stored. I want that when i click on a item, there is a substitution on the .url to include the first item clicked.

I hope this seems clearer to you.

Comment: It is very unclear of what you are exactly asking/trying to achieve? Show the code that you think would work instead of showing random code

Comment: I edited the post. I hope it's better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can let `enqueueAccordion` accept a callback and pass the current accordion as a parameter:

```
DropdownAccordion.prototype = {
    // ...
    enqueueAccordion: function (makeAccordions) {
        var accordions = makeAccordions(this);

        for (var i = 0; i < accordions.length; i++)
            this.accordions.push(accordions[i]);
        this.render();
    }
}

$(selector).data('dropdownaccordion').enqueueAccordion(function (_this) {
    return [
        {
            name: "Batiment",
            data: {
                url: "/trends/list/" + _this.path[0],
                method: 'GET',
                datatype: "json",
                timeout: 5000
        }
    ];
});
```

If you want to use `this` directly, you can temporarily attach the callback to the current accordion:

```
DropdownAccordion.prototype = {
    // ...
    enqueueAccordion: function (makeAccordions) {
        this.makeAccordions = makeAccordions;
        var accordions = this.makeAccordions();
        delete this.makeAccordions;

        for (var i = 0; i < accordions.length; i++)
            this.accordions.push(accordions[i]);
        this.render();
    }
}

$(selector).data('dropdownaccordion').enqueueAccordion(function () {
    return [ // Ajax parameters
        {
            name: "Batiment",
            data: {
                url: "/trends/list/" + this.path[0],
                method: 'GET',
                datatype: "json",
                timeout: 5000
            }
        }
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I dug through the expressjs code, and found how they do the URL substituion. It work with the path-to-regex module. It seems not to be developped for browserside so i had to found another solution.

@aaron inspired me, and i finally add the possibility to have a callback in place of the url :

```
{
            name: "Capteur",
            data: {
                url: function (path) {
                    return "/trends/list/" + path[0] + "/" + path[1]
                },
                method: 'GET',
                datatype: "json",
                timeout: 5000
            }
        }
```

By doing this, people are now able to modify the path based on the previous selection.